# Некорретно работает кликабельная область ссылки

Tags: html, css

В моей таблице в некоторых ячейках находятся ссылки. Чтобы увеличить пространство их кликабельности, я добавил им отрицательный **margin** и положительный **padding**. С ячейками, где одна ссылка, всё хорошо, но в той ячейке, где у меня две ссылки, разделённые знаком **/**, у той ссылки, что слева, кликабельная область не перекрывает символ пробела, находящийся справа. А мне хочется, чтобы перекрывал. На всякий случай предупреждаю, что я не хочу удалять пробел в этом месте и назначать ссылке другой **padding-right**.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    table { border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; }
    td a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 7px 8px;
        margin: -7px -8px;
    }
    td a:hover { color: red; }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link1</a> / <a href="#">link2</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте ссылке `position: relative`, это поднимет её над прочим содержимым.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    table { border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; }
    td a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 7px 8px;
        margin: -7px -8px;
        position: relative;
    }
    td a:hover { color: red; }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link1</a> / <a href="#">link2</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```